# How to get a random key

Tags: javascript, random, key

If I have the following:

```
var liststuff = {'key 1':'value 1', 'key 2':'value 2', 'key 3':'value 3'};
```

How should I go around to get a random key?

So the idea is that I would run a function and it will randomly give me one of the keys from liststuff, which I then could use to do what I want.

I though about giving 2 keys to each value, where the first one would be the 'key n', while the second key would be 'n-1' (n = number of keys):

e.g.

```
var belonging = {'Tom':'fish', 0:'fish', 'Jerry':'cheese', 1:'cheese', 'Billy':'pencil', 2:'pencil'};
```

And then I could do the following to get the random key:

```
let randChoice = Math.floor(3 * Math.random);
belonging[randChoice];
```

But then it would take too much space as the number of keys increases, and was wondering if there is a different and smarter way of doing this.

Comment: Have a look at [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get random index by `Math.random * keys.length` and then use that index to get a key.

```js
var obj = {'key 1':'value 1', 'key 2':'value 2', 'key 3':'value 3'};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var key = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do it in a simple way using The Object.keys() method which returns an array of a given object's property names.

```
var items = {'key 1':'value 1', 'key1':'value 2', 'key 3':'value 3'};
const allKeys = Object.keys(items)
const randomValFromItems = items[allKeys[Math.floor(Math.random()*allKeys.length)]];
```

Hope this helps